# assign value from another table column to the current select query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, unix-timestamp

i am writing this below query to fetch records for hour hour intervals

```
SELECT *
FROM gw_lob_store
WHERE created_ts<(round(((sysdate-interval '30' MINUTE) - to_date('19700101 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS'))*86400));
```

here minute '30' in the above query i want to fetch from another table column (below query) and assign it, please let me know how to do it

```
select prop_value
from gw_prop_config
where prop_name='lobStoreJobTime'
```

where prop_value is having the value '30' which i want to assign

NOTE: these two tables do not having any matching columns.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can replace the literal '30' in the INTERVAL expression with a variable.

However, since SYSDATE is a DATE and not a TIMESTAMP, `sysdate-interval '30' MINUTE` is equivelent to `sysdate-30/60/24` so you could re-write as:

```
SELECT *
FROM gw_lob_store
WHERE created_ts < round(((sysdate-(select to_number(prop_value)/60/24
                                      from gw_prop_config
                                     where prop_name='lobStoreJobTime'
                                   )
                          ) - date '1970-01-01'
                         )*86400
                        )
```

Comment: `prop_value` is probably a string (because such config columns usually are) so the usual defensive datatype casting may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mainly options:

1) A 30 minute interval equals 30 one-minute intervals:

```
sysdate - (interval '1' minute * prop_value)
```

2) Calculate the minutes from the number:

```
sysdate - numtodsinterval(prop_value, 'minute')
```